What does the 'debug in error log' checkbox do in Charles Proxy?
I'm using Charles proxy 4.6.6 on Mac and I usually use the rewrite feature which is very helpful. But in the rewrite window popup, there is a 'debug in error log' checkbox... when checked/unchecked, I do not notice any difference. Anyone knows the function? Is there something I'm missing?

